# css 960 grid clearfix not working but clear:both does work

Tags: css, grid, clearfix

I am using grid 960 and cannot get clearfix to work, however if I use `clear:both` on the element, then I can get the desired effect. I would prefer to use clearfix as I find it more reliable (usually).

In the code below, the header section has a left logo area, and a right banner area and then underneath that should be a navigation bar.

This navigation bar is the element I am having difficulty with. If I add `style="clear:both;"` to the `nav` element, it works fine. However, it doesn't work if I use clearfix in the header element.

[Here is the page that does not work (using clearfix)](http://niumata.com/test2.html)

[Here is the page that works (using clear:both)](http://niumata.com/test.html)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/960_12_col.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="container_12 ">


    <header class="clearfix grid_12">
        <div id="logoarea" class="grid_6 alpha">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>iContinuity Directory Services</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                    [ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]
                    [ <a href="/Account/Register">Register</a> ]

            </div>
        </div><!-- end logoarea -->

        <div id="headerbanner" class="grid_6 omega">
            <p>this is the header banner area</p>
        </div>

        <nav class="">

            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
            </ul>

            <form action="/Search/Search" class="navsearch" method="get">
                <input class="textbox" id="search" name="search" type="text" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>  
        </nav>

    </header>


    <section id="main" class="grid_8 ">

        <h2>Welcome to iContinuity Services</h2>
        <p>

        </p>

    </section>



    <aside id="sidebar" class="grid_4">
        ontrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a lin
    </aside>


    <footer class="grid_12">
        <p>this is the footer area</p>
    </footer>

</div> <!-- end 960 grid container -->

</body>
</html>
```

I hope I have not done anything wrong that is glaringly obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: I must be missing something since clearfix is just doing clear:both anyway.

Comment: no clearfix adds much more than that.
it simulates adding an empty div, but it also has tricks for older browsers and lesser used browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you place an empty DIV just before your NAV element with a clearfix class on it then that should work.

Comment: let me try that and i will report back.... yes this does work, however I wanted to avoid adding in html. (the whole idea of cleafix was to avoid that)